# how can I generate GEE or paired data with multivarite normal distrubition?

Tags: correlation, simulation, paired-data, multivariate-normal-distribution, generalized-estimating-equations

I want to generate paired data and  all variables must have  multivaritare normal distrubition.
help me please ,
I have not find any codes for  paired data from multivaritare normal distrubition .
I want to correlated both all of variables and pre-post measures.

for example;
pre A-Post A; correlation = 0.5
pre B-Post B ; correlation = 0.5
pre C-Post C ;correlation = 0.5

preA-PreB-PreB ; correlation is 0,5 or corrlation matrix c(rA, rB, rC)
postA-PostB-PostB ; correlation is 0,5 or corrlation matrix c(rA, rB, rC)

I could only  generate multivarite normal data with  rmvnorm. these are not paired.

What I must do?

Comment: Do you mean `MASS::mvrnorm`? I would consider that to be paired data. Why do you not?

Comment: yes,I mean that.  I can generate multivariate data with this. In addition I want to generate paired  data.
 my data like this;
preX1- preX2-preX3-preX4-preX5-preX6-...-preX15
postX1-postX2-postX3-postX4-postX5-postX6-...postX15

X1-X2-X3..-X15 with multivariate norma distrubition for pre datas.
X1-X2-X3..-X15 with multivariate norma distrubition for post datas.
preX1-post1 must correlated because they are paired.
I can not do all  together